# Access sprites in Canvas?

Tags: html5-canvas, haxe, openfl, haxeflixel

Targeting HTML5 in `OpenFL` is easy, however, I could not add glowing effects to sprites, I am thinking of a work around, that is using JavaScript library to add webGL effects to the sprites in Canvas.

But, the question is, how would I access the sprites in`Canvas` using JavaScript? and what tool to use to inspect sprites in `Canvas` ?

Comment: The canvas element is essentially just a dynamic bitmap - it's one DOM element that can show the pixels of images, lines etc. So JS/HTML doesn't have the concept of a 'sprite', thus you can't 'inspect' it. Sprites only exist at the OpenFL level of abstraction. Thus, you will still have to work through/with OpenFL in some regard. I'll have a closer look at this today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of, since version 4.0 openfl uses webgl renderer by default and adding glow effect in that case requires a 'deep dive' into openfl/lime source code and i can't give you that.
But if that's suitable for you, force openfl to use canvas fallback with

```
<haxedef name="canvas"/>
```

and then you can create custom Bitmap class (for example) with glow effect like so

```
import openfl.display.Bitmap;
import openfl.display.BitmapData;
import openfl.display.PixelSnapping;
import openfl._internal.renderer.cairo.CairoBitmap;
import openfl._internal.renderer.canvas.CanvasBitmap;
import openfl._internal.renderer.dom.DOMBitmap;
import openfl._internal.renderer.opengl.GLBitmap;
import openfl._internal.renderer.RenderSession;

class HackyBitmap extends Bitmap
{

    /**
     * Custom property for tweening
     */
    public var glowBlur:Float = 0.0;    

    public function new(bitmapData:BitmapData=null, pixelSnapping:PixelSnapping=null, smoothing:Bool=false) 
    {
        super(bitmapData, pixelSnapping, smoothing);

    }


    public override function __renderCanvas (renderSession:RenderSession):Void {


        var context = renderSession.context;

        if (glowBlur > 0)
        {
            context.save();
            context.shadowBlur = glowBlur;
            context.shadowColor = "white";
        }


        CanvasBitmap.render (this, renderSession);

        if (glowBlur > 0)
        {
            context.restore();  
        }

    }

}
```

Usage

```
var data = Assets.getBitmapData("img/berry.png");
var hacky = new HackyBitmap(data);
hacky.x = hacky.y = 20;
addChild(hacky);

//to animate glow property
Actuate.tween(hacky, 1.0, { glowBlur: 50 }).repeat().reflect();
```

OpenFL/Lime versions

```
lime 3.2.0
openfl 4.2.0
```

How it looks

[image: regular vs glowy]

Comment: Great! Actually, I have no idea bout `RenderSession ` but would it be possible to use `Actuate` to tween context.shadowBlur ? Any place to read about context class (CanvasRenderContext in lime) documentation ?

Comment: Well, RenderSession is kind of undocumented, you can learn about it while reading lime/openfl source codes. And yes, you can use `Actuate` to tween `context.shadowBlur` but not directly, since `__renderCanvas` gets called every frame you can define a custom property on `HackyBitmap` which will be tweened, i'll update my answer in a minute.

Comment: Updated my answer with the tweening example.

Comment: Thanks! an answer I was dreaming to see :) How about changing color of  bitmap? for ex: like color transformation? would it be possible to use shaders too? or what do you think?

Comment: Can you please discussion here http://community.openfl.org/t/accessing-sprites-from-canvas-via-javascript-directly/8161/4 as I need to do color transform also, thank you

Comment: This request is out of the initial question's scope, please, create a new question with detailed explanation.

Comment: Hi, I have just applied your answer into my project, but once I force openFL to use canvas fallback `<haxedef name="canvas"/>` the performance would get poor! any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Well, as i said before, implementing webgl glow filter for openfl is not so easy, currently i have no time to implement it, but if i end up doing so i will post a link here.

Answer (score 0):

As said in my comment, `Sprites` don't exist in JS/HTML, it's an abstraction on top of `Canvas` that [ends up calling `.drawImage`](https://github.com/openfl/openfl/blob/826acbcac9c96e58af3e2e76cbd7b414e036b6a0/openfl/_internal/renderer/canvas/CanvasBitmap.hx#L53), thus, you won't find it in any browser developer tools. The only way you can 'access' these sprites is just by using what OpenFL provides - your sprite objects, BitmapData, etc.

The method you tried to get a glow was probably through the [GlowFilter](http://api.openfl.org/openfl/filters/GlowFilter.html) class, which is wrongly described as 'Avaliable on all platforms' in the docs. This class isn't implemented with the Canvas element yet, but [could have been](https://jsfiddle.net/kt4xfaef/15/).

However, WebGL exists for OpenFL, it isn't all canvas. That's why shaders are possible. There is a sort of glow filter for webgl, inbuilt into openfl, first shown in [this commit](https://github.com/openfl/openfl/pull/697/commits/b057fd6e3a406fdab14f5f7aa83759d54a409ac7) of [this pull request](https://github.com/openfl/openfl/pull/697). So using shaders might be your best bet.

Unfortunatly, shaders don't work with Canvas. I feel like doing [glows in canvas](https://jsfiddle.net/kt4xfaef/15/) would be your best approach, but it's not yet implemented.

Comment: There is a discussion with OpenFL founder here http://community.openfl.org/t/accessing-sprites-from-canvas-via-javascript-directly/8161/2 about this issue.. may be you can share thoughts there